# Remove repetitive code for multiple spinners using one listener

Tags: android, kotlin

I managed to setup multiple spinners using one listener but there is a lot of repetition in the code.

My full onItemSelected method:

```
 override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    when (parent.id) {
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_1 -> {
            val selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            mMeasurement1 = when (selection) {
                getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
                getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
                getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
                getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
                getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
                getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
                else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
            }
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_2 -> {
            val selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            mMeasurement2 = when (selection) {
                getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
                getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
                getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
                getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
                getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
                getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
                else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
            }

        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_3 -> {
            val selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            mMeasurement3 = when (selection) {
                getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
                getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
                getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
                getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
                getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
                getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
                else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
            }
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_4 -> {
            val selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            mMeasurement4 = when (selection) {
                getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
                getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
                getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
                getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
                getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
                getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
                else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
            }
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_5 -> {
            val selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            mMeasurement5 = when (selection) {
                getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
                getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
                getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
                getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
                getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
                getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
                else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
            }
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_6 -> {
            val selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            mMeasurement6 = when (selection) {
                getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
                getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
                getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
                getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
                getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
                getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
                else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
            }
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_7 -> {
            val selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
            mMeasurement7 = when (selection) {
                getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
                getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
                getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
                getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
                getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
                getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
                else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made a slight improvement since my original post but I think it can be improved.  Please let me know your suggestions!

```
 // Setup the dropdown spinner that allows the user to select the quantity for each ingredient.
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    // Checks the views in the adapter which are the views I associated to the adapter within
    // onCreate
    val measurementSpinnerOptions = when (parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String) {
        getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
        getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
        getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
        getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
        getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
        getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
        else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    }
    when (parent.id) {
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_1 -> {
            mMeasurement1 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_2 -> {
            mMeasurement2 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_3 -> {
            mMeasurement3 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_4 -> {
            mMeasurement4 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_5 -> {
            mMeasurement5 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_6 -> {
            mMeasurement6 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_7 -> {
            mMeasurement7 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_8 -> {
            mMeasurement8 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_9 -> {
            mMeasurement9 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
        R.id.spinner_ingredient_10 -> {
            mMeasurement10 = measurementSpinnerOptions
        }
    }
}


// Required function for onItemSelected.
override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
    mMeasurement1 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement2 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement3 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement4 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement5 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement6 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement7 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement8 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement9 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
    mMeasurement10 = DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ

}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use smth like `fun DataEntry.from(selection: String) = when (selection) { ... }`? Wait... why are you even switching on the id? The code inside the case looks identical (unless I'm missing something; I'm not an Android person.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Repetition

I have not tested this on Android, but I think something like this should work, storing the individual units in an array.

You can use getters if you want to still access them as measurementN

```
class T: Listener {
    val measurements = MutableList(7, {DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ})

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        when (parent.id) {
            R.id.spinner_ingredient_1 -> update(0, position, parent)
            R.id.spinner_ingredient_2 -> update(1, position, parent)
            R.id.spinner_ingredient_3 -> update(2, position, parent)
            R.id.spinner_ingredient_4 -> update(3, position, parent)
            R.id.spinner_ingredient_5 -> update(4, position, parent)
            R.id.spinner_ingredient_6 -> update(5, position, parent)
            R.id.spinner_ingredient_7 -> update(6, position, parent)
        }
    }

    fun update(item: Int, position: Int, parent: AdapterView<*>) {
        val selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
        measurements[item] = when (selection) {
            getString(R.string.measurement_oz) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
            getString(R.string.measurement_ml) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_ML
            getString(R.string.measurement_dash) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DASH
            getString(R.string.measurement_drop) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_DROP
            getString(R.string.measurement_cube) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_CUBE
            getString(R.string.measurement_garnish) -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
            else -> DataEntry.MEASUREMENT_OZ
        }
    }
}
```

**For completeness I have included the shim I used below**

```
class AdapterView<T> {
    val id: Long = -1
    fun getItemAtPosition(id: Int): String {
        return "MOCKED"
    }
}
class View
interface Listener {
    fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long)
}

class R {
    object id {
        val spinner_ingredient_1 = 0L
        val spinner_ingredient_2 = 1L
        val spinner_ingredient_3 = 2L
        val spinner_ingredient_4 = 3L
        val spinner_ingredient_5 = 4L
        val spinner_ingredient_6 = 5L
        val spinner_ingredient_7 = 6L
    }
    object string {
        val measurement_oz = 0L
        val measurement_ml = 1L
        val measurement_dash = 2L
        val measurement_drop = 3L
        val measurement_cube = 4L
        val measurement_garnish = 5L
    }
}

enum class DataEntry{
    MEASUREMENT_OZ,
    MEASUREMENT_ML,
    MEASUREMENT_DASH,
    MEASUREMENT_DROP,
    MEASUREMENT_CUBE,
    MEASUREMENT_GARNISH
}

fun getString(id: Long): String {
    return "MOCK"
}
```

Comment: Honestly your answer is way above my skill level so I had to study this for a bit.  I was able to use your code to simply.  Thanks!